# Linkedin ionic2 authentication

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, linkedin-api

Can anybody help me with Ionic2 LinkedIn authentication without using ionic services, stamplay or AuthO, I have written the code, configured the app on linkedin, but it seems there is a problem with it(configuration) as the LinkedIn Popup opens but doesn't generates any response after entering credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Note : I have used stamplay for linkdin
    //   install cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

```
declare var window: any;

export class HomePage {

 constructor(public platform: Platform,private http: Http) { 
  this.platform = platform;
  this.http = http;
 }  


 linkedlogin()
 {
   this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.linked().then(success => {
     //Generate  to the access token 
       let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
       let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
       this.http.get("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?client_id='Your clientID'&client_secret='your client_secret'&redirect_uri=https://ionic-li-login.stamplayapp.com/auth/v1/linkedin/connect&code="+ success + "&grant_type=authorization_code",
          options).map( res =>res.json()).subscribe(data => 
            { 
              var accessToken = data.access_token;
              //Get to the people data for login user data 
              this.http.get("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,industry,picture-url,headline,date-of-birth,location:(name))?format=json&oauth2_access_token=" + accessToken )
                .map( res =>res.json())
                .subscribe(showdata => { 
                  var linkdata = {
                          id:showdata.id,
                          firstName:showdata.firstName,
                          lastName:showdata.lastName,
                          emailAddress:showdata.emailAddress,
                          industry:showdata.industry,
                          headline:showdata.headline,
                          location:showdata.location.name,
                          pictureUrl:showdata.pictureUrl,
                   }
                   console.log(JSON.stringify(linkdata));
               });
             });
      }, (error) => {
      alert('Error');
    });

  });
}


linked(): Promise<any>
{ 
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) 
  {
    /* Linkedin login and signup page */
    var browserRef = window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id='your clientID'&redirect_uri=https://ionic-li-login.stamplayapp.com/auth/v1/linkedin/connect&scope=r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress");
    browserRef.addEventListener("loadstart", (event) => {
     if ((event.url).indexOf("https://ionic-li-login.stamplayapp.com/auth/v1/linkedin/connect") === 0) 
     {   
       browserRef.removeEventListener("exit", (event) => {});
       browserRef.close();
       /* Will be generate to the authentication code */
        var authcode = (event.url).split("code=")[1];
        if(authcode !=null)
        {       
          resolve(authcode);
        }
        else
        {
         alert("Problem authenticating with Linkdin");
        }
     }
   });
   browserRef.addEventListener("exit", function(event) 
   {
    reject("The Linkdin sign in flow was canceled");
   });
  });
 }
```

}

Comment: Mate you have used Stamplay whereas i am avoiding that and focusing more on the native plugin mentioned in the docs. If you can help me with that, it would be really helpful.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your help @HR Patel. I was able to solve it using the native plugin mentioned in the docs. :)